# Trouble with router.locale not being set in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm working on a Next.js application that involves internationalization (i18n) and localization. I'm trying to use the router.locale property from the next/router package to determine the current locale of the application, but I'm facing issues where the property doesn't seem to exist or returns unexpected results.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using in my LanguageSelect component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function LanguageSelect({}: {}) {
  const languageOptions = ['en', 'hu', 'kh', 'ng', 'ph', 'pk', 'th', 'vn'];
  const router = useRouter();
  const lang = (router.query.lang as string) ?? router.locale;

  // Rest of the component logic...
}
```

Despite importing useRouter correctly and setting up my next.config.js with the required locale configuration, I'm encountering issues where router.locale doesn't seem to exist or doesn't provide the expected values.

Why?